# How many spaced squares fit in outer square

Tags: geometry, area, packing-problem

[image]

Say I have an outer square like this, which is 14m x 14m. Each inner square is separated by a space of 3m, and one square is 1m$^2$. I of course have the image up, but how would I mathematically figure out that 16 squares fit inside?

Context: I'm approximating the number of trees within a specific area (Imagine looking down on the trees from a top, 2d view. To do that I broke the area up into squares (as shown), and now have to find how many trees fit in a single square.

Comment: Are you just considering this specific case (squares with side length 1 meter inside a square of side length 14 meters), or are you trying to get a more general solution for other cases as well? Is there some particular context that this question arose out of?

Comment: This was kind of just an example, a general solution would definitely be better. The context of this is approximating the number of trees within a specific area (Imagine looking down on the trees from a top, 2d view). To do that I broke the area up into squares (as shown), and now have to find how many trees fit in a single square. This example would be assuming every tree within a 14x14 square is separated by 3m.

Comment: oh that's cool! I would recommend editing your post to include what you've put in the comment. are you in general assuming that the trees (inner squares) are necessarily separated by 3m, or could it be other distances in other cases?

Comment: in general, if you're just looking at a $K$m $\times$ $K$m square, where $K$ is an integer, then you can break it up into $K^2$ squares which are each 1m $\times$ 1m (if you want to be completely mathematically explicit about it, then you can impose coordinates with the bottom left of the outer square as the origin and describe each of the $K^2$ squares as $[m, m+1] \times [n, n+1]$ for some $m, n \in \{0, \dotsc, K-1\}$). If each tree is just a 1m $\times$ 1m square, then you can fit $K^2$ of them.

Comment: Actually yes, the only true variable here in my context would be the space between each tree, so yeah it could be other distances in other cases.

Comment: Ok sure, so here we would 196 trees right assuming each tree is 1m x 1m. How would we incorporate the spaces between them at this point?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146114/discussion-between-jonathan-pal-and-marko).

Comment: It's best not to have extended discussions in comments about the question; can you edit your post to reflect the exact question you're asking (including your last couple of comments)?

Answer (score 2):

Let $x$ denote the length of the side a small square, $d$ the distance between small squares and $S$ the length of the side of the large square.

In order to get $n^2$ small squares inside the large square, the large square must have side length at least $S\ge nx+(n-1)d$.

In order for $S$ to be not large enough to accommodate $(n+1)^2$ small squares it must be the case that $S<(n+1)x+nd$.

$$\frac{S-x}{x+d}<n\le\frac{S+d}{x+d}=\frac{S-x}{x+d}+1$$
Applying this to your specific case, $x=1, d=3, S=14$ we get

$$\frac{13}{4}<n\le\frac{13}{4}+1$$

So $n=4$ and the number of small squares is $n^2=16$.